# How to make a smart pointer point to a copy of an object

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, memory-management, smart-pointers

How can I create a smart pointer that points not on the original object but on a copy of the object?

```
std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat> mat_p;
if(isChangePersistent){
    // Use a pointer on the original object
    mat_p = std::make_unique<cv::Mat>(&_img);
}else{
    // Use a pointer on a copy of the original object
    mat_p = std::make_unique<cv::Mat>(&(_img.clone()));
}
```

The idea is to work further in the code only with the pointer `mat_p`. This way I don't have to check anymore if I have to work on the original or on the copy since the pointer always points on the right object.

Compiling this code throws the error `error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]`. Only the second `std::make_unique` throws this error. `_img` is a member variable of the class in which this method is defined.

What I kind of understand, since I give the smart pointer the address of a temporary object. What is the right way to do this? Create the object with `new` and give that created pointer to the constructor of the smart pointer?

### Edit:

I updated my code, using `shared_ptr` and I tried to allocate the object in the else block in order to get rid of the error with the temporary address:

```
std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat> mat_p;
if (isChangePersistent) {
    // Use a pointer on the original object
    mat_p = std::make_shared<cv::Mat>(&_img);
} else {
    // Use a pointer on a copy of the original object
    cv::Mat* img_tmp = new cv::Mat();
    *img_tmp = _img.clone();
    mat_p = std::make_shared<cv::Mat>(img_tmp);
}
```

Now I get this error, already for the first `std::make_shared`:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat*)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

I don't really understand the problem anymore.

Comment: Is the error shown for both `std::make_unique` statements?

Comment: What is `clone()`?

Comment: Only to the second `std::make_unique`. I should add, `_img` is a member variable of the class in which this method is defined.

Comment: This is being made more difficult by having to use `clone` function rather than a copy constructor.

Comment: @MarkRansom The copy constructor of cv::Mat does not create a deep copy of the object: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a294eaf8a95d2f9c7be19ff594d06278e

Comment: @Jonas I just said it was harder, not that you didn't have a good reason to do so. P.S. making a `unique_ptr` from an existing object that you didn't freshly allocate isn't going to end well.

Comment: @MarkRansom The pointer exists only in this method. Though I could change it to a `shared_ptr` :)

Comment: Making a smart pointer to `&_img` looks extremely suspicious. If that's a stack object, you're going to have `delete` called on it, which is not good.

Answer (score 3):

`cv::Mat` is already a reference counted object. It is, essentially, like `shared_ptr<>`.
You don't ever really need to hold it in an external `shared_ptr<>`, `unique_ptr<>` or any other additional smart pointer wrapper.

Just use it as is.
If you have `cv::Mat img1, img2` then:

- `img2 = img1;` will make both variables share the same image (changing one will change the other).
- `img2 = im1.clone();` will give `img2` an independent copy of `img1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use `unique_ptr` for some reason then you should take use of a class's [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). Otherwise a `shared_ptr` works as well.

## C++11

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int n;
    A(int n = 1) : n(n) { }
    A(const A& a) : n(a.n) { } // copy constructor
};
 
int main()
{
    A *a1 = new A(1);
    
    std::unique_ptr<A> aptr(a1);
    std::unique_ptr<A> bptr(new A(*a1)); // Copy the object a1 points to
}
```

## Addressing after follow up question:

You're getting the error `error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat*)’` because the constructor for `Mat` does not have an overload that take a `Mat *` type. However your problem is more how you're trying to copy object rather than the lack of a constructor accepting a `Mat *`. Here's how you can resolve your error:

```
std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat> mat_p;
if (isChangePersistent) {
    // Use a pointer on the original object
    mat_p = std::make_shared<cv::Mat>(&_img);
} else {
    // Create a new shared pointer that holds a copy of _img on the heap
    mat_p = std::make_shared<cv::Mat>(cv::Mat(_img));
}
```

If you created cv::Mat then be sure you define an appropriate copy constructor for it otherwise `cv::Mat(_img)` will throw the same error you had in the follow portion of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`std::shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/):

> Objects of `shared_ptr` types have the ability of taking ownership of
>   a pointer and share that ownership: once they take ownership, the
>   group of owners of a pointer become responsible for its deletion when
>   the last one of them releases that ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers, both `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, are about establishing the lifetime of an object. You don't want to change how the lifetime of an object is managed if it's already being managed elsewhere.

In your case, the easiest solution is probably to use a *dumb* pointer and let the lifetime issue be completely independent.

```
std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat> mat_copy;  // not initialized unless needed
cv::Mat * mat_p;
if(isChangePersistent){
    // Use a pointer on the original object
    mat_p = &_img;
}else{
    // Use a pointer on a copy of the original object
    mat_copy = new cv::Mat(_img.clone());
    mat_p = mat_copy.get();
}
```